# bundle install against an older version of ruby for one gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, linecache

I can install the linecache (0.46) gem against ruby v 1.8.x, but not 2.0.0. When I run bundle install, I want to specify that I want to install all gems against 2.0.0 except linecache, which I want to install against 2.0.0. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just installing using an older version of ruby for all the gems. I used `rvm use "ree-1.8.7-2012.02"` and `bundle install`, and that worked.